# Using generic methods on SignalR Hub

Tags: c#, generics, signalr, signalr-hub, signalr.client

I'm creating a Hub class for my SignalR server and wanted to use a generic method which will save me from tons of lines of code. But SignalR is giving me errors when I try to Invoke the server code below from a Xamarin.iOS client which also in C#.

***Server Code***

```
public List<T> SendDataToClient<T>() where T : BusinessEntityBase
{
   return SomeDBManager.GetItems<T>();
}
```

***Client Code***

```
var list = await hubProxy.Invoke<List<Article>>("SendDataToClient");
```

Am I doing something wrong here or is it just impossible to use generic methods in SignalR Hubs?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You cannot invoke generic methods from SignalR clients. You'll notice that if you run `signalr ghp /path:myassembly.dll` against the dll containing the hub with the generic SendDataToClient method, you'll get the following error:

```
System.ArgumentException: Method System.Collections.Generic.List`1[T] SendDataToClient[T]() is a generic method definition
```

It's easier to see this error when using the [signalr ghp](http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/signalr-20/hubs-api/hubs-api-guide-javascript-client#manualproxy) command to generate a JavaScript hub proxy file, but this is the same error that is occurring on the server when you try to invoke SendDataToClient.

Comment: Thank you for clearance. So now I have to ask what would you recommend instead of this? Writing a function to hub for each different type of data?

Comment: That's the most straightforward approach.