# How to use generic hub in SignalR

Tags: c#, asp.net, signalr, signalr-hub

I am using SignalR in version 2.1.2. I have noticed there are two public hub classes for me to use, [`Hub`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.aspnet.signalr.hub.aspx) and `Hub<T>`. The former has an MSDN page which appears to be outdated and the latter lacks any MSDN page at all. I believe the MSDN documentation is not up to date with the latest version of SignalR from Nuget (which I'm using), because sources decompiled with the help of ReSharper show both of the classes inherit from `HubBase` base class. The MSDN page's Inheritance Hierarchy section shows the `Hub` class as inheriting from `Object` and implementing `IHub` and `IDisposable` interfaces, however the decompiled sources reveal the aforementioned `HubBase` base class, implementing the `IHub` interface which in turn implements `IDisposable`.

The difference between the non-generic and generic variant of the classes is that the non-generic one's `Clients` property returns `IHubCallerConnectionContext<dynamic>` while the generic variant returns typed `IHubCallerConnectionContext<T>`.

I'd like to have my clients typed, so when I call the client methods from the hub, I'd have proper Intellisense support and strongly-typed arguments. What I struggle with, though, is how to let the Hub know that my client model's method is actually to be invoked in the browser.

This is my `TestModel` class:

```
public sealed class TestModel
{
   public String Name { get; set; }
   public void Notify() {}
   public void NotifyComplex(TestModel model) {}
}
```

With the non-generic hub, I'd just call `.Notify()` or `.Notify(new TestModel() { Name = "sth" })` on the `dynamic`ly bound `this.Context.Clients.Client(…)` or `this.Context.Caller`, but with the generic class, when I call these empty methods in similar manner, the browser is not notified at all.

How do you use the generic hub class the way it's supposed to be used?

Comment: this might be useful: http://stackoverflow.com/a/21763587/526704

Comment: I'm afraid the question is unrelated. I am interested in calling client methods from the server, not the other way around, which is what the OP of that question is doing and the methods I want to call using RPC are not generic, the hub is, though, and so are its clients. I appreciate the comment, though.

Comment: i wasn't sure if it would be helpful or not, but i thought i'd provide what i found. sorry i don't have any other useful insight :(

Comment: Don't sweat it, the answer will be found eventually. :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I've found the answer. The MSDN documentation is not up-to-date as of yet, but the ASP .NET site offers nice SignalR tutorials and one of them covers the typed hubs:

http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/guide-to-the-api/hubs-api-guide-server#stronglytypedhubs

As the example in the article shows, if you use an interface for the type argument, everything works and you get strongly-typed hub clients whose methods are correctly translated to [RPC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Remote_procedure_call)s. Here's a piece of code  I tested this with:

```
public sealed class TestHub
  : Hub<ITestClient>
{
  public override Task OnConnected()
  {
    this.Clients.Caller.SayHello("Hello from OnConnected!");
    return base.OnConnected();
  }

  public void Hi()
  {
    // Say hello back to the client when client greets the server.
    this.Clients.Caller.SayHello("Well, hello there!");
  }
}

public interface ITestClient
{
  void SayHello(String greeting);
}
```

Comment: Keep in mind that in order for the `OnConnected` method to be called, you need to register a client method first: `$.connection.testHub.client.sayHello = function(g) { … }`. It is by design, that client, who cannot be called, does not trigger the `On[Connected|Reconnected|Disconnected]` methods and can only invoke the hub methods similarly to request-response paradigm.